# scipy curve_fit incorrect for large X values

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

To determine trends over time, I use `scipy curve_fit` with X values from `time.time()`, for example `1663847528.7147126` (1.6 billion).
Doing a linear interpolation sometimes creates erroneous results, and providing approximate initial `p0` values doesn't help. I found the magnitude of X to be a crucial element for this error and I wonder why?

Here is a simple snippet that shows working and non-working X offset:

```
import scipy.optimize

def fit_func(x, a, b):
    return a + b * x

y = list(range(5))

x = [1e8 + a for a in range(5)]
print(scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, x, y, p0=[-x[0], 0]))
# Result is correct:
#   (array([-1.e+08,  1.e+00]), array([[ 0., -0.],
#          [-0.,  0.]]))

x = [1e9 + a for a in range(5)]
print(scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, x, y, p0=[-x[0], 0.0]))
# Result is not correct:
#   OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
#   warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
#   (array([-4.53788811e+08,  4.53788812e-01]), array([[inf, inf],
#          [inf, inf]]))

Almost perfect p0 for b removes the warning but still curve_fit doesn't work
print(scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, x, y, p0=[-x[0], 0.99]))
# Result is not correct:
#   (array([-7.60846335e+10,  7.60846334e+01]), array([[-1.97051972e+19,  1.97051970e+10],
#          [ 1.97051970e+10, -1.97051968e+01]]))
   
# ...but perfect p0 works
print(scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, x, y, p0=[-x[0], 1.0]))
#(array([-1.e+09,  1.e+00]), array([[inf, inf],
#       [inf, inf]]))
```

As a side question, perhaps there's a more efficient method for a linear fit? Sometimes I want to find the second-order polynomial fit, though.

Tested with Python 3.9.6 and SciPy 1.7.1 under Windows 10.

Comment: Fitting procedure are sensitive to scale. Normalization is probably what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Root cause

You are facing two problems:

- Fitting procedure are scale sensitive. It means chosen units on a specific variable (eg. µA instead of kA) can artificially prevent an algorithm to converge properly (eg. One variable is several order of magnitude bigger than another and dominate the regression);
- Float Arithmetic Error. When switching from `1e8` to `1e9` you just hit the magnitude when such a kind of error become predominant.

The second one is very important to realize. Let's say you are limited to 8 significant digits representation, then `1 000 000 000` and `1 000 000 001` are the same numbers as they are both limited to this writing `1.0000000e9` and we cannot accurately represents `1.0000000_e9` which requires one more digit (`_`). This is why your second example fails.

Additionally you are using an Non Linear Least Square algorithm to solve a Linear Least Square problem, and this is also somehow related to your problem.

You have three solutions:

- Normalize;
- Normalize and change the methodology/algorithm;
- Increase the machine precision.

I'll choose the first one as it is more generic, the second one has been proposed by `@blunova` and totally makes sense, the latter is probably an inherent limitation.

#### Normalization

To mitigate both problems, a common solution is normalization. In your case a simple standardization is enough:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

y = np.arange(5)
x = 1e9 + y

def fit_func(x, a, b):
    return a + b * x

xm = np.mean(x)         # 1000000002.0
xs = np.std(x)          # 1.4142135623730951

result = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, (x - xm)/xs, y)

# (array([2.        , 1.41421356]),
# array([[0., 0.],
#        [0., 0.]]))

# Back transformation:
a = result[0][1]/xs                    # 1.0
b = result[0][0] - xm*result[0][1]/xs  # -1000000000.0
```

Or the same result using `sklearn` interface:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ("regressor", LinearRegression())
])

pipe.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)

pipe.named_steps["scaler"].mean_          # array([1.e+09])
pipe.named_steps["scaler"].scale_         # array([1.41421356])
pipe.named_steps["regressor"].coef_       # array([1.41421356])
pipe.named_steps["regressor"].intercept_  # 2.0
```

#### Back transformation

Indeed when normalizing the fit result is then expressed in term of normalized variable. To get the required fit parameters, you just need to do a bit of math to convert back the regressed parameters into the original variable scales.

Simply write down and solve the transformation:

```
 y = x'*a' + b'
x' = (x - m)/s
 y = x*a + b
```

Which gives you the following solution:

```
a = a'/s
b = b' - m/s*a'
```

#### Precision addendum

Numpy default float precision is `float64` as you expected and has about 15 significant digits:

```
x.dtype                            # dtype('float64')
np.finfo(np.float64).precision     # 15
```

But [`scipy.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) relies on [`scipy.least_square`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) which makes use of a squared metric to drive the optimization.

Without digging into the details I suspect this is where the problem happens, when dealing with values that are all close to `1e9` you reach the threshold where Float Arithmetic Error becomes predominant.

So this threshold of `1e9` you have hit is not related to the distinction between numbers on your variable `x` (`float64` has sufficient precision to make it almost exactly different) but on the usage that is made of it when solving:

```
minimize F(x) = 0.5 * sum(rho(f_i(x)**2), i = 0, ..., m - 1)
subject to lb <= x <= ub`
```

You can also check that in its signature, tolerances are about 8 decades wide:

```
scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun, x0, jac='2-point', bounds=(- inf, inf),
    method='trf', ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08, x_scale=1.0,
    loss='linear', f_scale=1.0, diff_step=None, tr_solver=None, 
    tr_options={}, jac_sparsity=None, max_nfev=None, verbose=0,
    args=(), kwargs={})
```

Which may let you tweak the algorithm to add extra steps before convergence is reached (if so) but that will not replace or beat the usefulness of normalization.

#### Methods comparison

What is interesting with [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html?highlight=linregress) method is the scale tolerance which is [handled by design](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.1/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py#L22-L209). The method uses variable normalization and pure linear algebra and numerical stability trick (see the `TINY` variable) to solve the LS problem even in problematic conditions.

This of course contrasts with the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` method which is a [NLLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) solver implemented as an optimized gradient descent algorithm (see [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)).

If you stick with linear least square problems (linear in terms of parameters not variables, so second order polynomial is LLS) then LLS is probably a simpler option to chose as it handles normalization for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just one minor question lingers: "Let's say you are limited to 8 significant digits representation" -- I assume scipy uses 64-bit floats like Python 3 in general, hence I didn't expect precision to be a problem here. But scale sensitivity is reason enough to change my code.

Comment: @AndersPetersson, I have added information related to your question in the answer. Let me know if it makes sense to you. Cheers

Comment: I didn't think about squaring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to compute a linear fit, I believe `curve_fit` is not necessary and I would just use the `linregress` function instead from SciPy as well:

```py
>>> from scipy import stats

>>> y = list(range(5))

>>> x = [1e8 + a for a in range(5)]
>>> stats.linregress(x, y)
LinregressResult(slope=1.0, intercept=-100000000.0, rvalue=1.0, pvalue=1.2004217548761408e-30, stderr=0.0, intercept_stderr=0.0)

>>> x2 = [1e9 + a for a in range(5)]
>>> stats.linregress(x2, y)
LinregressResult(slope=1.0, intercept=-1000000000.0, rvalue=1.0, pvalue=1.2004217548761408e-30, stderr=0.0, intercept_stderr=0.0)
```

In general, if you need a polynomial fit I would use NumPy [polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).